# Merge multiple Series as a single column into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frames:

A.

```
   k  m  n
0  x  x  x
1  x  x  x
2  x  x  x
3  x  x  x
4  x  x  x
5  x  x  x
6  x  x  x
7  x  x  x
8  x  x  x
9  x  x  x
```

B1.

```
   l   i  j
1  x  46  x
2  x  64  x
3  x  83  x
9  x  70  x
```

B2.

```
   l   i  j
0  x  23  x
4  x  34  x
6  x  54  x
8  x  32  x
```

B3.

```
   l   i  j
0  x  11  x
5  x  98  x
7  x  94  x
9  x  80  x
```

How can I add the column "i" (from data frames B1, B2, and B3) to the data frame A?

Regarding the duplicate values (e.g. index 9 in B1 and B3 & index 0 in B2 and B3), I want to keep the leftmost value from `[B1, B2, B3]` (e.g. 23 for index 0 & 70 for index 9).

A desired output would be:

```
   k  m  n   i
0  x  x  x  23
1  x  x  x  46
2  x  x  x  64
3  x  x  x  83
4  x  x  x  34
5  x  x  x  98
6  x  x  x  54
7  x  x  x  94
8  x  x  x  32
9  x  x  x  70
```

Comment: Can you provide a desired output A?

Comment: @null: I edited my original post with the desired output A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the Bx dataframes, and use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) on the index to remove the duplicated index and keep the first.

```
A['i'] = (pd.concat([B1, B2, B3])
            .loc[lambda x: ~x.index.duplicated(keep='first'), 'i'])
print(A)
   k  m  n   i
0  x  x  x  23
1  x  x  x  46
2  x  x  x  64
3  x  x  x  83
4  x  x  x  34
5  x  x  x  98
6  x  x  x  54
7  x  x  x  94
8  x  x  x  32
9  x  x  x  70
```